# Does StoreKit handle the download of non-consumable Apple-hosted in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

How does the download part work when the content is hosted with Apple? Does Store Kit take care of this? Does it resume interrupted downloads when transactions are resumed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you starting watching the video from the WWDC 2012 "Session 302 - Selling Products with Store Kit".

The video explains in detail how to adopt the App Store Hosted Contend part and also has a demo of how it works.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#302